# Convert Varchar value having no separators (ddmmyyyyhhMMss format) to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a date value stored in `varchar` variable without any separators, i.e. in the form `ddmmyyyyhhMMss`, like this: `@charDateTime='19022016122219';`

How can I convert it to a `DateTime` type variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just build a string in a suitable format and use [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx). I prefer style 126 (ISO8601): `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss`.

```
-------------------------------------ddmmyyyyhhMMss
-------------------------------------12345678901234
DECLARE @charDateTime varchar(50) = '19022016122219';
DECLARE @dt datetime;

-- style 126 (ISO8601)
-- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (no spaces)

SET @dt = 
    CONVERT(datetime, 
    SUBSTRING(@charDateTime, 5, 4) + '-' +    -- yyyy
    SUBSTRING(@charDateTime, 3, 2) + '-' +    -- mm
    SUBSTRING(@charDateTime, 1, 2) + 'T' +    -- dd
    SUBSTRING(@charDateTime, 9, 2) + ':' +    -- hh
    SUBSTRING(@charDateTime, 11, 2)+ ':' +    -- MM
    SUBSTRING(@charDateTime, 13, 2)           -- ss
    ,126);

SELECT @dt;
```

**Result**

```
(No column name)
2016-02-19 12:22:19.000
```